# Dynamically pass parameter to Elementor's HTML Code block

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a page created with Elementor. Nothing fancy. Just a `Section`, inside of which there is a `Column`, inside of which there is an `HTML Code` block. Inside the HTML block there is just an iFrame, like `<iframe src="https://app.squarespacescheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=xxxxxxxx" title="Schedule Appointment" width="100%" height="800" frameBorder="0"></iframe><script src="https://embed.acuityscheduling.com/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`...

The above URL of the iFrame is the general appointment scheduling of the owner `xxxxxxxx` of the Squarespace; but there are also more specific URLs, like `<iframe src="https://app.squarespacescheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=xxxxxxxx&appointmentType=yyyyyyyy" title="Schedule Appointment" width="100%" height="800" frameBorder="0"></iframe><script src="https://embed.acuityscheduling.com/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`, which refer to a specific task `yyyyyyyy` of the owner `xxxxxxxx`...

So what I basically want is to be able, instead of creating 15 different pages, each with the appropriate `yyyyyyyy` task value, to create just one page withouth the `appointmentType` param in the iFrame's URL, and then pass somehow the param with the appropriate value, when calling the page itself.

Is this even possible though, or should I do it the hard/boring way of creating each page for each task? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was relatively easy once I found the correct resource... So I'm sharing it here, in case anyone needs it in the future!

Basically it's all explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CBLIWeSmz30

The only difference in my case was that **probably** the code of the iFrame was complicated enough, and I was hitting some escaping issue, resulting in the last part of the code (`<script src="https://embed.acuityscheduling.com/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`) to getting lost...

So I had to deviate slightly from the suggested solution, and instead I followed the shortcode solution. So I added a shortcode with the following snippet:

```
add_shortcode('scheduler_iframe', 'scheduler_iframe_func');
function scheduler_iframe_func($atts)
{
    return '<iframe src="https://app.squarespacescheduling.com/schedule.php?owner=xxxxxxxx&appointmentType=' . $atts['course'] . '" title="Schedule Appointment" width="100%" height="800" frameBorder="0"></iframe><script src="https://embed.acuityscheduling.com/js/embed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';
}
```

From there, it was just a matter of setting up correctly the appropriate settings in Elementor. So for that, I replaced the *HTML block* with a *Shortcode block*, and instead of adding the shortcode in the appropriate field, I chose *Request Parameter*, then I set it up like in the images below:

[image: Settings tab]

[image: Advanced tab]

Finally visiting the URL of that page and passing the appropriate `?course=yyyyyyyy` querystring in the URL, was enough to fetch the appropriate iFrame that I wanted to show!